# Can I convert between .doc and .docx using PHP only?

Tags: php, file, docx, doc

I have search for this on SO but all posts relating to the issue seem to require the installation of software (like the Zend framework or PHPdocx) on the server - which I am not able to do.

I need to be able to read and update text in templates from .doc files. I can achieve this using PHPWord but it only works with .docx. I have contacted the developer of PHPword about the issue but support for .doc is very unlikely.

If there was a way to achieve this using PHP, that would be fantastic. Perhaps there is an internet application with an API which I could use to convert my files using PHP (Google Docs?) but none that I have found.

Perhaps [the Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) would help but I have no idea how that is used.

Comment: You could do the DOC parsing yourself, re-inventing PHPdocx. The real boundary here is not "how to do it", but removing whatever barrier is preventing you from installing the proper libraries.

Comment: I would have literally no idea how to do that

Comment: If you know why you can't install the library, then you should be able to work out how to solve that problem.

Comment: `Perhaps the Google Docs API would help but I have no idea how that is used.` Perhaps. More research required, then.

Comment: I looked into it. All the information refers to the Zend Framework.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment 'If you know why you can't install the library, then you should be able to work out how to solve that problem.' I cannot install the library because my host doesn't allow me to install software on the server.

Comment: Then it's time to change to a server that provides the control and functionality that you need. Or have you tried just asking them to install this PHP extension?

Comment: They I don't think such drastic measures as moving away from this host are necessary when I there may well be better and simpler options to explore

Comment: It's hardly drastic. It's using the correct tool for the job. Clearly you do not have sufficient latitude to implement the tools that you want to implement, so you should use a setup that has more flexibility. That's the real issue here. Sure, you could use some inferior solution to hack around the fact that you're lacking access to install third-party libraries, and that might "work okay" for a while, but then in a few months' time you'll need to do it again. And then again, and then again. Before you know it, your entire application is a mess of inferior reinventions of existing libraries.

Comment: Why would I need to redo it? Why must that such a solution be inferior? I think that '_the_ correct tool' is jumping to the conclusion that other equally valid solutions do not exist. You may be right but I see no reason why I should jump to dismiss the possibility that there may be better or equally viable ways to perform the same task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to just support .docx and if I can find some way of converting to .doc I will include that (but I have not found a way yet)